# Can anyone tell me what does this mean

Tags: c++, c

This is a very basic doubt, but clarify me please

```
#define TLVTAG_APPLICATIONMESSAGE_V             "\xDF01"
printf("%s\n", TLVTAG_APPLICATIONMESSAGE_V);
```

means what will be printed.

Comment: GCC 4.3.4 [does not compile this](http://ideone.com/yWb1d). Where did you find it? Does it compile for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To go step by step (using the C++ standard, 2.13.2 and 2.13.4 as references):

The `#define` means that you substitute the second thing wherever the first appears, so the `printf` is processed as `printf("%s\n", "\xDF01");`.

The `"\xDF01"` is a string of one character (plus the zero-byte terminator), and the `\x` means to take the next characters as a hex value, so it attempts to treat DF01 as a number in hex, and fit it into a `char`.

Since a standard quoted string contains `char`s, not `wchar_t`s, and you're almost certainly working with an 8-bit `char`, the result is implementation-defined, and without the documentation for your implementation it's really impossible to speculate further.

Now, if the string were `L"\xDF01"`, its elements would be `wchar_t`s, which are wide characters, normally 16 or 32 bits, and the DF01 value would turn into one character (presumably Unicode) value, and the print statement would print characters \xDF and characters \x01, not necessarily in that order, since `printf` prints `char`, not `wchar_t`.  `wprintf` would print out the whole `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 4):

It seems somebody is trying to print an [unicode character](http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0xDF01/index.html) -> �

Comment: Somebody wants to print a Unicode character in the worst way.